Snippet - Change Add to Cart Button
I need a snippet code to change add to cart button to below text (if the product is on back order:
Back Order (1-5 weeks to arrive)
Do anyone knows how to make the snippet!
What I need is the below:
If the product is on back order, the (Add to Cart) button changes to On Back order (Please allow 1 – 5 weeks to delivery this item)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
